# file_get_contents not working when getting FTP url

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7

I need to get the content of the CSV file for importing. I was given an URL which to use, you can see bellow, and I use this code:

```
print_r(file_get_contents('ftp://*username*@*host*:*password*@*host*/nagyker_csv.csv'));
```

When I tested on my server, it always returned empty. So, I tried to do it on my localhost, and it returned the content correctly.

I though that there was something in the php.ini file that prevented the function from working, so I tried to get the content of the main page of Google, and it returned correctly.

So, on the server, I can get content of any URL, except for the FTP, the one I need, but the URL is accessible, and as I said, I accessed it with the same code from my localhost.

The code is in Drupal 7 module, maybe that can cause problems?

Does anyone have any idea what could cause this? Maybe some server settings?

Comment: it's probably because you do not have URL wrappers enabled in PHP.

Comment: But I can get content of, let's say for example Google.com, but not that FTP that I need.

Comment: Can you use this alternative and try? `<?
    $filename = "ftp://username:pa‌​ssword@hostname/path/to/file";
    $handle = fopen($filename, "r");
    $contents = fread($handle, filesize($filename));
    fclose($handle);
    
    echo $contents;
    ?>` Please let me know if this works well.

Comment: Tried, it's not working, returns empty. I also tried with cURL, same result.

Comment: Then may be your file or path is wrong. Check the path is proper or not.

Comment: The path is alright, I used the same code on my localhost and it returned the file content. I also tried on PHPFiddle with file_get_contents, also returned the content. But on my server, always empty.

Comment: Can you please check the file permission and set as 0777 and then try again?

Comment: Just looked at permission, it is 0644

Comment: Can you please change the permission to 0777 and then check please?

Comment: Just did, it did not help, still getting empty. I am able to get the content everywhere, tried on localhost, except on the server.

Comment: Check if it returns http : `<?php
print_r(stream_get_wrappers());
?>`

Comment: Just tried, it does

Answer (score 0):

First, Please check file permission.

```
<?php  
      $username = "username";  
      $password = "********";  
      $url = "mydomain.com/file.txt"; // IP address also works in place of domain.com  
      $hostname= "ftp://$username:$password@$url";  
      $contents = file_get_contents($hostname);  
    ?>
```

Comment: have you checked file permission ?

Comment: Defauls is 0644, I changed to 0777, but still no luck.

Comment: same code I am using. can you please try with 777 ?